# Prevent price to auto-update

Tags: ms-access

I would like to ask how can i prevent price to be auto-updated.

For example:

Parts table has NAME, PRICE

On february 21 i created invoice 1 and in that time price for 1080 TI was 500$

Than on february 28 price changed to 650$ and same i created invoice.

But the problem is that when i update price in parts table (for invoice 2) also price for invoice 1 gets changed from 500$ to 650$ and i want to prevent this.

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only read the price when creating the invoice.

Save the unit price in the invoice line table when creating the invoice.

*Alternatively*, save a price change with the date it is valid from. Then, when pulling the price for the invoice, look up the price with the newest date older than or equal to the date of delivery or the date of the invoice.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses three tables.

**Parts**

- PartID = AutoNumber
- PartName = Text
  ***Primary Key** = PartID*

*Example*

```
+----------+--------+
| PartName | PartID |
+----------+--------+
| MyPart   |      1 |
+----------+--------+
```

**Prices**

- PartID = Number (Foreign Key)
- Price = Currency
- StartDate = Date/Time
  ***Primary Key** = (PartID, StartDate)*

*Example*

```
+--------+---------+------------+
| PartID |  Price  | StartDate  |
+--------+---------+------------+
|      1 | £500.00 | 01/06/2017 |
|      1 | £650.00 | 01/02/2018 |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

**Invoices**

- InvoiceID = Number
- PartID = Number (Foreign Key)
- InvoiceDate = Date/Time
  ***Primary Key** = (InvoiceID, PartID, InvoiceDate)*

*Example*

```
+-----------+--------+-------------+
| InvoiceID | PartID | InvoiceDate |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
|         1 |      1 | 02/06/2017  |
|         2 |      1 | 01/03/2018  |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

This SQL will then pull back the relevant price for the invoice date:

```
SELECT InvoiceID
       , InvoiceDate
       , PartName
       , Price
FROM   (Invoices Inv LEFT JOIN Parts ON Inv.PartID = Parts.PartID)
                     LEFT JOIN Prices P1 ON Inv.PartID = P1.PartID AND
                                            Inv.InvoiceDate>=P1.StartDate
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM    Prices P2
            WHERE   P2.PartID = P1.PartID AND
                    P2.StartDate<=Inv.InvoiceDate AND
                    P2.StartDate>P1.StartDate
                    )
```

*Example*

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| InvoiceID | InvoiceDate | PartName |  Price  |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
|         1 | 02/06/2017  | MyPart   | £500.00 |
|         2 | 01/03/2018  | MyPart   | £650.00 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

Source as I forgot the ins and outs....
[how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row)

Comment: Thank you for help!